# Link SDK only + Entity Framework = System.ComponentModel build error

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin

With linking set to SDK Only, I have an error on iOS like this:

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void
> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider::.ctor(System.Type)',
> referenced from the method
> 'System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor
> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider::GetTypeDescriptor(System.Type)'
> in 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.3.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I use Entity Framework and a number of other 3rd party libraries that integrate with Entity Framework, and in the past I have needed to add a --linkskip argument for System.Core or a .Init call in my Appdelegate file for Sqlite, but these techniques havent helped me with this ComponentModel issue. I assume it's because of Entity Framework or one of the related 3rd party libraries I'm using since I know they use a lot of reflection. Has anyone run into this before?

- EntityFrameworkCore.Triggers 1.2.2
- LinqKit 1.1.17
- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core 3.1.6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 3.1.3
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 3.1.2
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.1.2
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.3
- Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore 3.0.69

The projects using entity framework are class libraries that target .netstandard 2.0, and my main application uses xamarin forms 4.5 (have tried updating to 5.0 with no success)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem manually referencing System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll in .netstandard2.1 in nuget folder. You can try first to install the Annotations Nuget e if doesn't work you can try to manually reference.